# Database architecture question: 1 table per customer or 1 unique table for all customers

Tags: sql, database-design, product

We have a need to know which database architecture makes more sense to use and why.

We have a list of customers who are all going to use the same table structure (with very few exceptions).

We would have about 10 thousand customers who might all have all about 50 thousand products each.

The processing on products may not be the same for each customer and we would also want to provide a plan where customers could have API access to their data.

Our customers do sell products and their SQL table structure would all have columns such as :

- Feed_ID
- Product_ID
- Product_Description
- Price
- Weight
- etc...

The `Feed_ID` is used to differentiate the origin of these products and will be unique for each customer - of course.

The 3 choices of relational table structure that we have thought about:

1. Each customer has its own database and in that database, he has 1 table per product-feed
2. All customers are hosted under 1 unique database under which all customers all have 1 table per feed - in that case, 1 customer can have 2 tables if he as 2 different product feed.
3. All customers are hosted under 1 unique database, HOWEVER, in this 3rd solution, we only have 1 unique table that host all products feed of all customers.

Which solution would you use and why you think that the solution you selected is better?

Thank you.

Comment: Option #3 is the only one which makes sense and is remotely scalable.  Don't use the first two options.

Comment: There is no good or bad answer. It all depends on your requirements. What is the number of customers, what is their lifecycle (will they be added or not), will you have features same for all customers always, how will you manage bug fixes for each customer etc. etc. While @TimBiegeleisen, is pointed for option #3 as default, if it is multi-tenant setup for example, where customers should have access to their data only, you may choose option #2 as well. This will make management of your customers independent from each other for example.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. We would have 10 thousand customers who might all have all 50 thousand products each. 1 huge SQL table as in solution 3 is attractive, however always accessing the same table for any customer may bring some performance issues, also if for whatever reason that table gets corrupted then all customers lose their access. Also, If that unique SQL table gets hacked, the hacker has access to all customers data with that 1 table. Even then I am still not sure which solution is best?

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve]. PS Please clarify via post edits, not commments.

Answer (score 8):

You haven't quite provided enough information.  Under almost all circumstances (see below for exceptions), you want one set of tables for all customers.  Here are some reasons:

- Performance.  A proliferation of tables means the data is spread through more data pages, so you have lots of partially filled data pages.  The database is bigger and processing is slower.
- Coding efficiency.  If the tables for a customer all have different names, then all the code is dynamic SQL.  That is harder to maintain.
- Maintenance.  Adding a column or index is very arduous when there are zillions of similar tables.
- Analytics.  When similar data is spread through tables, it is really hard to answer questions such as "Which client has the most products?".
- Security.  Granting access permissions on a single set of tables is less error prone than on zillions of tables.

And no doubt, I've missed a few reasons.  You can see that it is almost a no-brainer to have a single database with a small number of tables.

There are situations where *separate databases* might be called for.  I cannot think of a good reason to have separate tables for each client in a single database.

The number one reason would be security and isolation.  There might be a business or even legal reason for storing data into "physically" separate databases, to further minimize the possibility of one client seeing another client's data (accidentally or through hacking).

Another reason would be if clients had bespoke solutions. That is, there are per-client customizations.  I would still be inclined to try to put this into a single database solution, but that might not be possible.

Related to this would be an application that you intend to support both in the cloud and on premises.  In that case, separate databases per client would probably simplify the application design.

But, in general, you would store the data in a pretty normalized single database, with one table per entity.

Comment: I agree we did not provide enough details in our question.
I love you reply and I feel/agree that the 1 table-for-all approach is very attractive.

However:
Is accessing 1 big table really providing better performance than 10K tables?
Security? With 1 table u would need it set at the record level, wouldn't that be more challenging?
About "dynamic SQL", would U really hardcode the name of that table in all your code?

Updating a column name or its type across 10K tables would be a real nightmare, yes I agree.
 
Any advantages to using the 1 table-per-customer approach?

Comment: Hmm... On a shared tenancy, if you have, say, 10 clients, it may be perfectly reasonable to split the schema such that each client gets its own table, especially if each client is storing hundreds of millions of records in that table. There are numerous advantages. For example, migrating client data is simpler, because it's all grouped in one table. You store less data, because you don't need a 'client-id' column in the table... it's baked into the table name. Scripts solve the 'maintenance' issue. The tables are still huge, individually, so they're not fragmented. Indexes are shallower.

Comment: Basically, this post's advice is good if you have a huge number of clients with a little data each. But it's not necessarily good advice if you have a handful of clients with lots of data each. In the latter case, segmenting the data into one table per entity per client could actually increase performance, ease maintenance (forces you to script it out in a repeatable fashion, which you should be doing anyway), and so on. The whole point you still want these clients on the same server and all that goes with sharing resources (obviously separate servers if resources are exhausted).

Comment: @Triynko . . . You could just as easily use table partitioning for performance (most databases support such functionality).  If the data is stored in a single database, then it is already combined for backup/restore purposes and probably for security as well (depending on the database). If so, it should probably be in one table.  If you want to split the client data, split it into separate databases.

Answer (score 2):

I think having separate tables (or ideally schemas) for each customer is not that bad idea. In addition to benefits you mentioned, this way you can scale your database easily, and you can give customers full control of their data if they want to.

Regarding the drawbacks:

- Managing it is more complicated but not as bad either - you can write
  a script to create columns/tables/indexes/etc. You
  don't have to do it manually.
- It will be a challenge to perform    analytics on 10K tables,
  although it's not the best idea to mix it with production anyway.
  I'd create a separate database (or server)  for analytics, running
  some overnight job to update reporting tables.

Also, if your table is going to have hundreds of millions rows (10Kx50k?), it's a good idea to split it into smaller pieces, regardless which option you'll choose. If not by customer, then by region or some other bigger group (assuming you are building on premises RDBMS)

Comment: "if your table is going to have hundreds of millions rows (10Kx50k?), it's a good idea to split it into smaller pieces".  This is just simply false and displays a complete lack of understanding of databases and how they scale.

Comment: In my opinion, smaller tables size would NOT improve performance as no hard-disk driver can access 2 different HD space at the exact same time. 
Performance would be improved if these "split" tables are placed on a completely different server. Again, if the file is too big, it means too many customers using the same file, it means too many requests at the same time, so yes to splitting but then move that other file to a different server.